# Java alert pop up not showing in PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, popup, alert

I've looked through other posts, and can't quite find the answer I'm looking for. I'm a REALLY new PHP programmer...

I currently have the following code:

```
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
}
```

which currently redirects to a blank, white page with `$error_message` displayed. What I actually want is an error box to pop up with the error, and the user to stay on the same page. I've tried doing this to get the box (based on other posts I found on here):

```
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert($error_message); </script>';
}
```

but I still get no pop up, and now with no `died` statement, the form behaves as a success... I've also tried writing the java block outside of PHP as well, with the same behaviour.

Thanks for any and all help, and remember, be nice - I'm still learning!

MORE INFO:

OK, turns out that `dies` is a call to a function (serves me right for trying to edit someone else's code!). I've now recoded the error statement and moved it up to that function block. I now get the error box as I hoped for, but when I click on it, I still get redirected to a blank page... I tried putting in a back statement as I'd seen on another thread, but no avail...

```
function died($error) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("'.$error.'"); </script>';
    history.back();
}
```

Comment: That's too broad to answer here. You need to look for ajax; post your form using javascript and use the results you get back to put up your alert box.

Comment: Java !== JavaScript...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a PHP variable inside of single quotes. This means it will *not* be interpolated. It needs to be inside double quotes or use concatenation. You're also missing quotes around that string value in your JavaScript:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("'.$error_message.'"); </script>';
```

FYI, the proper function in your other code is `die()` not `died()`.

Comment: Thanks for that... the changes worked, partially. See above for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess, but maybe you're being re-directed on every submit because your input form is located at "yourdomain.com/form.php" and your form's action attribute is aimed at "send.php"; if that's the case (it's impossible to tell whether it is from your example) you'll never be able to see the form with the error message on the same page...

Good luck